# packets for motives

Tags: reductive-groups

I want to know if there exists a set of motives that corresponds to automorphic representations of a reductive group. Such a set must be divided into sets of the same L(or ε）function and satisfy the strong multiplicity one theorem. Do we know such a set and packets exist without any artificial flavor (conjecturally)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do we have a (conjectural) classification of motives in terms of L(or ε)-functions that matches the packet theory of automorphic representations of a reductive group?
How is GL2-case(i.e. an equivalent form of modularity conjecture) generalize to a reductive group?